# area enclosed by level curve

Tags: calculus, geometry

Fix $a\in [0,1]$ and consider the closed curve

$
C_a:= \{ (x,y) : \sin(x) \sin(y) = a,\ (x,y)\in [0,\pi]\times[0,\pi]\}.
$

See contour plot of function $\sin(x) \sin(y)$. I am interested in computing the area of the enclosed by $C_a$ as a function of $a$. Is there a simple analytical form?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A partial answer:

First, change your variables $x \to \pi/2 - x$ and $y \to \pi/2 - y$ so your integral becomes:

$$4 \int\limits_{x = 0}^{\cos^{-1} a} \cos^{-1}\left( \frac{a}{\cos x} \right)\ dx$$

which should be clear from the plot:

[image]

Unfortunately, there seems to be no closed form for arbitrary $a$.  (Of course you can perform the integration numerically for an assigned value of $a$.)

You seem to be *Mathematica* literate, so use this instead of your code and insert your value for $a$ in the Contour level:

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x] Cos[y],
 {x, -π/2, π/2},
 {y, -π/2, π/2},
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
 Axes -> True,
 Contours -> {0.1}]
```